# how to toggle mobile emulation through javascript/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am creating a fun little project for myself that I do not intend to publish.

I am looking for a way to automate something but I am having a bit of trouble because what I want to do requires me to switch between desktop view and mobile emulated view (rather, I am only doing one switch, from desktop -> mobile). And by mobile emulated view, I mean true emulation, not simulation.

So, part of my code is to open a link in a new tab. I want the new tab to be either in desktop view or mobile view. I can do this manually by enabling "always open dev tools on popups" and having mobile emulation enabled (in developer options) on my current tab. If it is enabled beforehand, the popup will open in a new tab with developer options enabled and mobile emulation enabled.

Is there a way to code the switch so that the whole process is automated? Do I have to tweak some settings on my browser or launch it with specific arguments?

Security issues is not a problem with me. I am the only one using it and I have a separate browser (Edge) that only runs this website.

Thanks.

Opening the link inside the current tab and making the iframe size small to SIMULATE mobile view does not work as it is not the intention of the program. It has to be true mobile EMULATION. Though, I have not tried some really sophisticated approach in doing this. This solution may actually work but I am not experienced enough to figure this out.

Comment: a web page can't manipulate the browser in that manner for obvious reasons

Comment: Yeah, I figured I was stretching a bit. Thanks for letting me know.